# Is Azure VM Spot instance normal or Low priority?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Is Azure Spot VM instance standard or low priority? At https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/spot-vms the first answer in FAQ section says that it is normal. I used L8s v2 spot instance yeasterday and in billing csv export (setuped in menu: Cost Management + Billing > Cost Management > Exports) says that my instance was Low Priority.

[image: Spot VM Usage in report marked as Low Priority]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/spot/) in the FAQ:

> The preview of Azure low-priority VMs on scale sets has been discontinued and will be retired after January 1, 2020. Spot VMs—now in preview—have replaced Azure low-priority VMs and will include new capabilities, such as variable pricing. Spot pricing is also available on both single VMs and VMSS. Variable pricing will become effective at a future date.

Comment: This do not answer my question I think. I had read somewhere that old low-priority VM has lower resource priority, that means that for example CPU performance of standard-priority instance will be priorized on the physical host and you can expect better performance than on low-priority instance. But for new spot instances which replaced old-priority VMs there are in FAQ written that it has same parameters as standard instance. So my question is that we can expect that the spot instance has the same weight as normal instance or still it has lower weight like low-priority VM in old days?

Comment: Ah, ok: There was never a difference in the resource priority, even with low-priority VMs. the concept was the same with the new spot instances. They could be evicted at any time. I'd say the "low priority" rather refers to the workloads you would run on them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this doesnt really make sense:

```
Q: Once created, is a Spot VM the same as regular standard VM?
A: Yes, except there is no SLA for Spot VMs and they can be evicted at any time.
```

this says the VM is the same (CPU\Memory\NICs\etc). but priority would be low. since you are allowing Azure to get rid of your VM at anytime if Azure needs capacity. SO its pretty much low priority VM's